# How to get component value from ActionEvent object?

Tags: jsf, ajax4jsf, jsf-1.1

i am using ajax4jsf with jsf 1.1 and i have code like:

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="INPUT_PO_DocCategory" binding="#{PrinceOfficeBean.PO_DocCategory}" style="width:200px;">
          <f:selectItem itemLabel="test" itemValue="123"/>
          <f:selectItem itemLabel="test2" itemValue="456"/>
         <a4j:support event="onchange" actionListener="#{PrinceOfficeBean.processDocumentCategoryValueChange}" reRender="INPUT_PO_DocType" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

this code is static and i can get selectOne value through `PO_DocCategory` binded object
the question is: is it possible to get the component value in actionlistener through the action event object ?

```
public void processDocumentCategoryValueChange(ActionEvent e) throws Exception {
   // get component value from ActionEvent 
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Classic way in JSF is to use value attribute of input component, e.g.:

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.value}">
    ...
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

The input value will be stored in `value` attribute of the `bean`, and can be used by action listener to operate on.

It is still possible to get the value in action listener in 'alternative' way:

```
((EditableValueHolder) event.getComponent().getParent()).getValue()
```

Comment: ,this gets the selectOneMenu value, right ? and how to get the selectOneMenu id in this case ?

Comment: @MahmoudS Have you tried event.getComponent().getParent().getId()?