# How to get component value from ActionEvent object in Primefaces?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2

I am using ui-repeat and inputtext using primefaces

```
<ui:repeat var="field" value="#{formSettings.studentsFormSettings}" varStatus="form">

                <h:outputLabel value="#{field.label}"
                    rendered="#{field.type eq 'TEXT'}" />
                <br />
                <p:inputText required="#{field.valdaite}" 
                    requiredMessage="#{field.requrid}" disabled="#{!field.active}"
                    rendered="#{field.type eq 'TEXT'}" >
                </p:inputText>

</ui:repeat>
```

and i am have call method

```
public void listener(ActionEvent actionEvent){
    actionEvent.getComponent().getParent().getAttributes();
        UIComponent tmpComponent = actionEvent.getComponent();
}
```

how can i get all values from input text using primefaces ?

Comment: You could implement a property `#{field.value}` with get and set method and pass it to `<p:inputText value="#{field.value}" ...>`

Comment: Did you read these answers you have been pointed to in your previous question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18203481/how-to-set-submitted-values-of-hinputtext-inside-uirepeat-into-map-set-or

Comment: The answer is: The same way as in plain JSF: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20309576/how-to-get-component-value-from-actionevent-object

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get component value from ActionEvent object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20309576/how-to-get-component-value-from-actionevent-object)